# HTML hyperlink not working for paragraph

Tags: html

I have two divs that act as links (`<a>`). One in one paragraph, the other in the second paragraph. The second link works: on mouseover (in Chrome) the bottom left of the window displays the link address. The top one does not do the same. What is wrong? I'm talking about the links in the paragraph tags, not the menu links.

```
<body ontouchstart>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="logo">Q<sup>3</sup></div>
   <div class="desc">Quito's Qustom Qode</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="sidenav col2">
    <a id="about" class="link-active">about</a>
    <a id="pricing">pricing</a>
    <a id="projects">projects</a>
    <a id="legal">legal</a>
   </div>
  </div><!-- /row -->

  <div class="row">
   <div id="content" class="col10">
    <div class="info">

     <div class="about">

      <div class="profile-back">
       <div class="profile"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="about-me">
       <p>Kevin (Quito [Key'-tow]) Williams is an aspiring front-end web designer. He has 5 years of experience in HTML, 4 years experience in CSS, and is currently studying jQuery. As a modern web designer, he is using his coding background to study the latest web technologies: HTML5, CSS3, <a href="http://www.google.com">RWD</a>. In addition to his web technology languages, he is also familiar with: C<sup>++</sup>, Javascript, Java, Perl, Lua (Minecraft based), LISP, SQL. </p>
       <p><a href="http://www.google.com">Hello</a></p>
```

Comment: add target="_blank" in your a href tag.check my below answer.

Comment: Your paragraph links were working in proper only i don't know what issue u are facing.. You gave ```http://www.google.com``` for ```RWD``` and ```Hello``` and both works fine and the hover over it also shows the corresponding link in bottom left of the window.. I think this issue only u was asking and its working fine for me.. And also be sure that u were posting a code here in stackoverflow with correct opening and closing tags, Which was missing a lot in your code..

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a bit more clear about what outcome you are expecting?

Edit: I think i understand now, "About" "Pricing" "Projects" should be hyperlinks?

you are missing the "href" attribute in the  tags which should fix your problem.

If you don't want the link to direct to a different page, you can use href="#" to stop this.

Are you on about the following lines?

```
    <a href="http://www.google.com">RWD</a>.
    <p><a href="http://www.google.com">Hello</a></p>
```

If so, both are working fine in chrome and IE for me. I'm not sure what the issue is for you.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to add the actual link on your anchor tags through href.

Your current code:

```
<a id="about" class="link-active">about</a>
<a id="pricing">pricing</a>
<a id="projects">projects</a>
<a id="legal">legal</a>
```

Changes:

```
<a href="#" id="about" class="link-active">about</a>
<a href="#" id="pricing">pricing</a>
<a href="#" id="projects">projects</a>
<a href="#" id="legal">legal</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code,add target="_blank" in your a href

```
   <p><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Hello</a></p>
```

And the working fiddle link is here https://jsfiddle.net/p7mnsj3p/